Difference of behaviors between Virtual Threads & Classical Threads regarding 'synchronized'?
A lot of open-source projects are trying to get away from using syncrhonized due to its behavior with Virtual Thread.
Regarding Virtual Threads, I understand that within a synchronized block, in situations where network communication (which would normally park the thread) or file I/O occurs, the Carrier Thread should ideally be handed over to another thread, but it remains "pinned." Is my understanding correct?
Is the situation different with traditional ThreadPool-based multithreading? In cases where asynchronous processing occurs within a synchronized block, can the Carrier Thread be properly handed over to another thread?
Additionally, does a similar issue occur during the process of acquiring a Lock to execute a synchronized block? In other words, when another thread is executing a synchronized block and the Virtual Thread is waiting, does it remain pinned until the lock is released?
My questions could be summarized as below:
public void someMethod() {
    // Does Virtual Thread get pinned here, too?
    synchronized(this) {
        someIOMethods() // Virtual Thread gets 'pinned' here, right? How about classical ThreadPools?
    }
}


A virtual thread has an OS thread behind it executing. When the virtual thread blocks, the OS thread can start working on something else if it is not pinned to it's carrier (for example in a synchronized block). When you're using a 'classical thread' it is tied to an OS thread. If it blocks, then the OS thread blocks. There isn't a handoff where the OS thread can go do other work.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/core/virtual-threads.html#GUID-2BCFC2DD-7D84-4B0C-9222-97F9C7C6C521 Oracle calls 'classical threads' platform threads.

@matt, so that means in worst case scenario(when virtual threads get pinned), it at least behaves the same as 'classical threads'(OS thread getting blocked), right?

In terms of blocking, yes. It will remain tied to the host thread. A platform thread is always tied to the host thread.

If not a virtual thread, then the thread represented by a Java Thread object is a host OS thread. A Java platform thread is a host OS thread, one and the same. Every Java platform thread is a host OS thread, but not every host OS thread is a Java platform thread.


public void someMethod() {
    // Does Virtual Thread get pinned here, too?
    synchronized(this) {
        someIOMethods() // Virtual Thread gets 'pinned' here, right?...
    }
}


A virtual thread that calls someMethod() will be pinned to its carrier while it executes inside the synchronized block. It doesn't "get pinned" again when it calls someIOMethods() because it already is pinned. The someIOMethods() call happens inside the synchronized block, and the thread is pinned for the entire duration of that block.

...How > about classical ThreadPools?

"Pinned" means, the carrier thread is unable to execute the code of any other virtual thread until it exits from the synchronized block.
A classic thread pool worker thread can only work on one task at a time. Once it picks a task from the pool's task queue, it is unable to execute the code of any other task until it completes the one that it picked. Compared to how virtual threads work, it's as if the thread pool worker is always "pinned." It was pinned before it ever entered someMethod().

Thanks for your answer. I want to ask two more things - 1. Does 'acquiring the lock' also pin the virtual thread? For example, if a virtual thread called someMethod() and another called it simultaneously, it would wait until the former thread finishes, right? Does it pin the virtual thread to a carrier thread? /// 2. So basically a thread pool worker thread is always pinned to a carrier thread, so that it will always hold the carrier thread during the whole operation?

Sorry, typed enter without realizing that it immediately adds the comment. I edited the original comment to add new questions. Thanks in advance.

Re, "Does 'acquiring the lock' also pin...?" Uh,... Does "lock" mean Lock, as in, java.utils.concurrent.locks.Lock? You mentioned a Lock in your question, but there is no such thing in your code example, and I do not understand what you meant when you said, "...acquiring a Lock to execute a synchronized block."

I asked the question this way because my understanding of 'entering a synchronized block' is that the caller somehow 'acquires the lock'. Sorry for the lack of clarity (my bad). Please consider 'acquiring the lock' as 'entering the synchronized block'.

Re "basically a thread pool worker thread is always pinned to a carrier." I would not say it exactly like that. I said, "compared to how virtual threads work it's as if the worker is always 'pinned'." I said "as if" and I put scare quotes around "pinned," because normally, we would only ever use the words "pinned" and "carrier" when we are talking about virtual threads.
